# PIC32 System clock <-> Peripheral clock

Tags: pic, oscillator, configuration

In a demo software from Olimex for the PIC32-MAXI-WEB the configuration words for the osc are set as follows:

```
/** CONFIGURATION **************************************************/

#pragma config FNOSC    = PRIPLL        // Oscillator Selection
#pragma config FPLLMUL  = MUL_20        // PLL Multiplier
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_2         // PLL Input Divider
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_1         // PLL Output Divider
#pragma config FPBDIV   = DIV_1        // Peripheral Clock divisor
```

There are the following macros for getting the clock speeds;

```
#define SYS_CLOCK             (80000000ul)
#define GetSystemClock()      (SYS_CLOCK)
#define GetPeripheralClock()  (SYS_CLOCK/2)
#define GetInstructionClock() (SYS_CLOCK)
```

The main clock should be 8MHz / 2 * 20 / 1 = 80

Is the PeripheralClock = SYS_CLOCK/2 a bug/typo, as the FPBDIV is set to 1. I tried to look for it in the datasheet. Is there indeed a bug, or is there some kind of internal division by 2 that is always active or activated by some other condition/register. (Like how the instruction clock was FOsc/4 on some devices)

Comment: What's the definition of DIV_1?

Comment: @Madmanguruman I think it is somekind of a compiler (xc32) constant. A quick search turns out: `CVALUE:00000000:DIV_1:1x Divider` in `xc32/v1.21/pic32mx/lib/proc/<device>/configuration.data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. The peripheral clock should be equal to the system clock if you set FPBDIV = DIV_1.

So it should be:

```
#define GetPeripheralClock()  (SYS_CLOCK)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a better way of defining peripheral clock would be:

```
#define GetSystemClock()            (80000000ul)
#define GetInstructionClock()       (GetSystemClock())
#define GetPeripheralClock()        (GetSystemClock()/(1<<OSCCONbits.PBDIV))
```